# Toggle/Hide Anchors(Objects) and Trackables(Planes) in (Android ARCore SDK & Sceneform) to take both screenshots/record both videos

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

Is it possible to create an app where I can take a screenshot of a particular field of view where I can have a screenshot of the same field of view without any Anchors(Objects) and Trackables(Planes) being seen on the screenshot and another screenshot of the same field of view with the Anchors(Objects) that i placed and Trackables(Planes). And I want both the images of the exact field of view(There should not be a pixel of difference of the background field of view on which I placed the anchor objects).

Is it possible to do this in Android with ARcore with sceneform or unity even?

Is it possible to replicate this with video also (Like 1 video without the Anchors(Objects) and Trackables(Planes) and 1 with  the Anchors(Objects) and Trackables(Planes) )

There is also 1 more question that I have - Can we make the Anchors(Objects) and Trackables(Planes) invisible somehow even though they already are in the field of view and are not hidden away)

Please help, I am a beginner

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this problem?